# R - Dplyr - How to mutate rows

Tags: r, rows, dplyr

I found that dplyr is speedy and simple for aggregate and summarise data. But I can't find out how to solve the following problem with dplyr.

Given these data frames:

```
    df_2017 <- data.frame(expand.grid(1:195,1:65,1:39), 
                         value = sample(1:1000000,(195*65*39)),
                         period = rep("2017",(195*65*39)),
                         stringsAsFactors = F)

    df_2017 <- df_2017[sample(1:(195*65*39),450000),]

    names(df_2017) <- c("company", "product", "acc_concept", "value", "period")

    df_2017$company <- as.character(df_2017$company)
    df_2017$product <- as.character(df_2017$product)
    df_2017$acc_concept <- as.character(df_2017$acc_concept)
    df_2017$value <- as.numeric(df_2017$value)

 ratio_df <- data.frame(concept=c("numerator","numerator","numerator","denom", "denom", "denom","name"),
ratio1=c("1","","","4","","","Sales over Assets"),
ratio2=c("1","","","5","6","","Sales over Expenses A + B"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

where the columns in df_2017 are:

- *company*     = This is a categorical variable with companies from 1 to 195
- *product*     = This is a categorical, with home apliance products from 1 to 65. For example, 1 could be equal to irons, 2 to television, etc
- *acc_concept* = This is a categorical variable with accounting concepts from 1 to 39. For example, 1 would be equal to "Sales", 2 to "Total Expenses", 3 to Returns", 4 to "Assets, etc
- *value*       = This is a numeric variable, with USD from 1 to 100.000.000
- *period*      = Categorical variable. Always 2017

As the expand.grid implies, the combinations of *company - product - acc_concept* are never duplicated, but, It could happen that certain subjects have not every *company - product - acc_concept* combinations. That's why the code line "df_2017 <- df_2017[sample(1:195*65*39),450000),]", and that's why the output could turn out into NA (see below).

And where the columns in ratio_df are:

- *Concept* = which acc_concept corresponds to the numerator, which one to
  denominator, and which is name of the ratio
- *ratio1* = acc_concept and name for ratio1
- *ratio2* = acc_concept and name for ratio2

**I want to calculate 2 ratios (ratio_df) between acc_concept, for each product within each company.**

For example:

I take the first ratio "acc_concepts" and "name" from ratio_df:

```
num_acc_concept   <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "numerator", 2]
denom_acc_concept <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "denom", 2]
ratio_name        <- ratio_df[ratio_df$concept == "name", 2]
```

Then I calculate the ratio for one product of one company, just to show you want i want to do:

```
ratio1_value <- sum(df_2017[df_2017$company == 1 & df_2017$product == 1 & df_2017$acc_concept %in% num_acc_concept, 4]) / sum(df_2017[df_2017$company == 1 & df_2017$product == 1 & df_2017$acc_concept %in% denom_acc_concept, 4])
```

Output:

```
output <- data.frame(Company="1", Product="1", desc_ratio=ratio_name, ratio_value = ratio1_value, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

As I said before I want to do this for each product within each company

The output data.frame could be **something like this (ratios aren't the true ones because I haven't done the calculations yet)**:

```
company    product   desc_ratio              ratio_value
1           1        Sales over Assets           0.9303675
1           3        Sales over Assets           1.30
1           7        Sales over Assets           Nan
1           1        Sales over Expenses A + B   Inf
1           2        Sales over Expenses A + B   2.32
1           3        Sales over Expenses A + B    NA
2
3
and so on...
```

- NaN when ratio is 0 / 0
- Inf when ratio is number / 0
- NA when there is no data for certain company and product.

I hope I have made myself clear...

Is there any way to solve this row problem with dplyr? Should I cast the df_2017?

Comment: I can not follow what you are trying to achieve. What exactly would the new dataframe look like? Can you manually produce a minimal working example? 
The example of rate 1, do you want the calculated independently for each subject and subitem? E.g. For item 3 subject 1 has 35 subitems. Are you wanting a rate1 for each subitem? or can you average the subitems and calculate a rate1 for each item.
What are the rules for calculating rates? rate1 = item3/item6 what you rate2 be?
I can't see how this would come together

Comment: I've edited the post for better understanding. I answer each question: 1) " The example of rate 1, do you want the calculated independently for each subject and subitem", yes, that's what I want. 2)  "Are you wanting a rate1 for each subitem?" Yes, that's what I want. 3) "or can you average the subitems and calculate a rate1 for each item" No, I don't want averages. 4) " rate1 = item3/item6 what you rate2 be? " There are nearly 20 rates, i think. I will have another data.frame with the items needed to calculate each rate. There are rates that involve more than one item in the numerator...

Comment: ... or denominator. For example (items 1 + items 2) / items 3. But the main problem is how to divide rows between them. Because, unlike sum or multiply, division needs an order, and i think the only way to achieve that is casting the data.frame, i think.

Comment: I lost myself between "items" and "subitems" just like @George. Could you please define them mathematically using some numbers and examples?